# Is 'chaining' functions available in GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to 'chain' functions?  Say, I have a serverclickhandler and then would like to invoke another function after it right away.  How do I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just call the other function directly?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't seem to get the desired result.

Can I do like this?

function soso(e) {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   
   //manipulate app var and other stuff

   //can I call another function here?  This other function would also need to manipulate the active application as well

   return app;

   //or should I put the function call here?
}

Comment: we never do a `UiApp.createApplication();` on a handler, you should clarify your question, probably add some code.

Comment: I just wanted to explore the idea first before coming up with a bunch of codes.

What I want is to fire up another function right after a function  called by a handler is executed BUT I would like that second function to be called within or at the very end of the first.

Just wanted to know if that's doable.  I apologize if "chaining" is confusing or not the right term.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a second handler executed after the first one you just need to call it directly from your first handler, e.g.

```js
var app = null;
function firstHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your thing

  //now, instead "return app;" you return the second handler
  return secondHandler(e);
}

function secondHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your job
  return app;
}
```

I placed the `app` var on a global scope so you can get it only when necessary (sharing it between the functions without explicit passing it), saving a possibly costly and unknown behavior (to me at least) of a second `getActiveApplication()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understood exactly your question but serverhandlers to which you refer are precisely made for that... ([see doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_user_interfaces?hl=fr-FR#UIUpdate))
Note that you can assign multiple handlers to UI elements to trigger different functions and eventually chain them.

Comment: I understand multiple handler assignments.  My question is: Are the handlers/functions run in succession? Will GAS wait for the first function to finish before executing the next one or are they fired up synchronously?

Thanks for answer, Serge.

Comment: OK.  That answers my question then.  Chaining, the way I envisioned it, is not doable in this context.

Thanks Henrique.