# How can chained functions access form data in Google Apps Scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

This question is an extension of "[Is 'chaining' functions available in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10821521/is-chaining-functions-available-in-gas)."

I need to do something similar... copy/pasting the code example which answered the previous question:

```
var app = null;
function firstHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your thing
  //now, instead "return app;" you return the second handler
  return secondHandler(e);
}

function secondHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your job
  return app;
}
```

Where firstHandler() is the click handler for a button. The difference between this example and what I need to do is that, in my case, secondHandler() needs to pull a piece of information from a form. Specifically, I need to get the selected value from a List box.

Normally, the way I would have secondHandler() pull that info in would be to pass the parent object containing the list box into the function, then have a line like this:

```
var value = eventInfo.parameter.listBoxName;
```

However, I'm having trouble passing the grid that the list box sits within into secondHandler(). Here's what I've tried:

```
var app = null;
function firstHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your thing
  //get the object now, pass it into the chained function
  var myGrid = app.getElementById("gridId");
  return secondHandler(myGrid);
}

function secondHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var value = e.parameter.listBoxName.toString();
  //do your job
  return app;
}
```

But this hasn't been working. I've also tried modifying secondHandler() to be completely argument free, such that I can bypass having to pass the grid into secondHandler() within firstHandler():

```
var app = null;
function firstHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your thing
  return secondHandler(e);
}

function secondHandler(e) {
  if( app == null )
    app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var value = app.getElementById('listBoxId').value;
  //do your job
  return app;
}
```

This doesn't work either... "app.getElementById('listBoxId').value" doesn't seem to return anything. I have no idea why not :(

Any thoughts about how I can do this? Anyone know why my app.getElementById workaround isn't behaving as expected? Any and all help appreciated!!!

Comment: Try replacing `var app = null;` with just `var app;`. I believe setting a variable outside functions like that makes it constant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function firstHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  //do your thing
  return secondHandler(e);
}

function secondHandler(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var value = e.parameter.listBoxName;
  //do your job
  return app;
}
```

Be sure that you use this when creating the handler.

```
app.createServerHandler("firstHandler").addCallbackElement(gridContainingListBox);
```

If you're retrieving values from the page, you **have** to use `e.parameter` which is properly set when you add the proper callback element. If you're going to be modifying elements in the UI, then you can certainly use `app.getElementById(...).whateverFunction()`, but just note that you can't call `getValue()`, etc.

Comment: You can certainly use the `if (app==null)` lines, but I have never experienced an issue with calling getActiveApplication() twice.